# Objects.hash returning different hashCodes for equal objects

Tags: java

Given the following class:

```
package software.visionary.identifr;

import software.visionary.identifr.api.Authenticatable;
import software.visionary.identifr.api.Credentials;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class PasswordCredentials implements Credentials {
    private final Authenticatable owner;
    private final byte[] value;
    private final SecretKey key;

    public PasswordCredentials(final Authenticatable human, final String password) {
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(password).trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid password");
        }
        this.owner = Objects.requireNonNull(human);
        this.key = asSecretKey(password);
        this.value = this.key.getEncoded();
    }

    private SecretKey asSecretKey(final String password) {
        try {
            final PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
            final SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
            return secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final PasswordCredentials that = (PasswordCredentials) o;
        return owner.equals(that.owner) &&
                Arrays.equals(value, that.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(owner, value);
    }  
}
```

And the following tests:

```
package software.visionary.identifr;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import software.visionary.Randomizr;
import software.visionary.identifr.api.Authenticatable;
import software.visionary.identifr.api.Credentials;

import java.util.UUID;

final class PasswordCredentialsTest {
    @Test
    void rejectsNullOwner() {
        final Authenticatable owner = null;
        final String password = Randomizr.INSTANCE.createRandomPassword();
        Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> new PasswordCredentials(owner, password));
    }

    @Test
    void rejectsNullPassword() {
        final Authenticatable owner = new Authenticatable() {
            @Override
            public Credentials getCredentials() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public UUID getID() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        final String password = null;
        Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> new PasswordCredentials(owner, password));
    }

    @Test
    void rejectsEmptyPassword() {
        final Authenticatable owner = new Authenticatable() {
            @Override
            public Credentials getCredentials() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public UUID getID() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        final String password = "";
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new PasswordCredentials(owner, password));
    }

    @Test
    void rejectsWhitespacePassword() {
        final Authenticatable owner = new Authenticatable() {
            @Override
            public Credentials getCredentials() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public UUID getID() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        final String password = "\t\t\n\n\n";
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new PasswordCredentials(owner, password));
    }

    @Test
    void hashCodeIsImplementedCorrectly() {
        final Authenticatable owner = Fixtures.randomAuthenticatable();
        final String password = Randomizr.INSTANCE.createRandomPassword();
        final PasswordCredentials creds = new PasswordCredentials(owner, password);
        final int firstHash = creds.hashCode();
        final int secondHash = creds.hashCode();
        Assertions.assertEquals(firstHash, secondHash);
        final PasswordCredentials same = new PasswordCredentials(owner, password);
        Assertions.assertEquals(creds.hashCode(), same.hashCode());
        final PasswordCredentials different = new PasswordCredentials(owner, Randomizr.INSTANCE.createRandomPassword());
        Assertions.assertNotEquals(firstHash, different.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    void equalsIsImplementedCorrectly() {
        final Authenticatable owner = Fixtures.randomAuthenticatable();
        final String password = Randomizr.INSTANCE.createRandomPassword();
        final PasswordCredentials creds = new PasswordCredentials(owner, password);
        Assertions.assertTrue(creds.equals(creds));
        final PasswordCredentials same = new PasswordCredentials(owner, password);
        Assertions.assertTrue(creds.equals(same));
        Assertions.assertTrue(same.equals(creds));
        final PasswordCredentials different = new PasswordCredentials(owner, Randomizr.INSTANCE.createRandomPassword());
        Assertions.assertFalse(creds.equals(different));
        Assertions.assertFalse(different.equals(creds));
    }
}
```

**`hashCodeIsImplementedCorrectly()` is failing in a way I don't expect: two objects that satisfy the `equals` contract are returning different hashcodes.** [This seems in direct violation of the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

I'm just using [`Objects.hash` in the recommended, IDE auto-generated manner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-)...

> This method is useful for implementing Object.hashCode() on objects containing multiple fields. For example, if an object that has three fields, x, y, and z, one could write:
>
> ```
> @Override public int hashCode() {
>     return Objects.hash(x, y, z);
> }
> ```

Am I missing something obvious? I haven't had this problem before, and written lots of unit tests for equals()/hashCode().

I shudder to think, but in case it's relevant...

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.119.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.119.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, if objects `A` and `B` are equal (in the sense that `A.equals(B)` returns `true`, they should have the same hash code. By extension, if you implement your `equals` method by checking the equality of a series of fields, using `Objects.hash` should provide a proper hashcode.

But this isn't what you're doing here - you're using `Arrays.equals` to compare two arrays - as you should. Arrays with the same **contents** are **not equal**, and thus may (and probably will) have different hash codes. Instead, you can use [`Arrays#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-byte:A-) to get `value`'s hash code:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(owner, Arrays.hashCode(value));
    // Here -------------------^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the generated `equals` method more closely gave it away: it's because `value` is a `byte[]`. When using arrays as fields, `Objects.hash` needs to use `Arrays.hashCode(value)`.

This works correctly:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(owner, Arrays.hashCode(value));
    }
```